# Error in connecting to SSRS after migration

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a machine "A" where initially my SSRS reports were deployed. It is a 32-bit server with SQL Server 2008. Now I migrated the reports from SQL Server 2008 to 2012.

I deployed my reports SQL Server 2012 on machine "B" which is again a 32-bit server.

Now when I try to access my SSRS Reports, the one connecting to SQL DB are working fine, but the one connecting to Oracle is throwing following error:

Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Earlier too I was connecting to same Oracle DB through SSRS reports and it wasn't throwing any error.

Comment: Did you install the Oracle client and set up TNSNAMES on the new server?

Comment: Yes, It is installed. Oracle client 10 and 11g.